# Is there a way to add species to an ISOMAP plot in R?

Tags: r, vegan

I am using the **isomap-function** from **vegan** package in R to analyse community data of epiphytic mosses and lichens. I started analysing the data using NMDS but due to the structure of the data ran into problems which is why I switched to ISOMAP which works perfectly well and returns very nice results. So far so good... However, the output of the function does not support plotting of species within the ISOMAP plot as species scores are not available. Anyway, I would really like to **add species information** to enhance the interpretability of the output.

Does anyone of you has a solution or hint to this problem? Is there a way to add species kind of *post hoc* to the plot as it can be done with environmental data?

I would greatly appreciate any help on this topic!

Thank you and best regards,
Inga

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no function to add species scores to `isomap`. It would look like this:

```r
`sppscores<-.isomap` <-
    function(object, value)
{
    value <- scale(value, center = TRUE, scale = FALSE)
    v <- crossprod(value, object$points)
    attr(v, "data") <- deparse(substitute(value))
    object$species <- v
    object
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
`sppscores<-.isomap` <-
    function(object, value)
{
    wa <- vegan::wascores(object$points, value, expand = TRUE)
    attr(wa, "data") <- deparse(substitute(value))
    object$species <- wa
    object
}
```

If `ord` is your `isomap` result and `comm` are your community data, you can use these as:

```r
sppscores(ord) <- comm # either alternative
```

I have no idea (yet) which of these alternatives is more correct. The first adds species scores as vectors of their linear increase, the second as their weighted averages in ordination space, but expanded so that we allow some species be more extreme than the site units where they occur.

These will add new element `species` to the result object `ord`. However, using these in **vegan** would need more coding, but you can extract the species scores with `vegan::scores`, but their scaling is based on the original scale of community data, and may be badly scaled with respect to points of site units, and working on this would require more work. However, you can plot them separately, or then multiply with a constant giving similar scaling as site unit scores.

```r
sp <- scores(ord, display="species", choices=1:2)
plot(sp, type = "n", asp = 1) # does not allow plotting text
text(sp, labels = rownames(sp)) # so we must add text
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your incredibly fast and helpful reply, Jari, you made my day! I just implemented your suggestion and it works out like a charm. If I am correct even the problem with scaling of species scores can be solved by using 'ordipointlabel' instead of 'text' to add the species names.